# Algorithm for Simple Squared Squares

Tags: algorithm, math, shapes

I want to split a square in unequal squares.
After some search on the web found [this Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square).
This is an output i need :

[image]

Does anyone have idea for this?

Comment: Downvoters please provide some comments.

Comment: @shekharsuman I searched for the algorithm but i couldn't find anything, So i answer here.

Comment: This is a good question, I think it'll take some time!

Comment: @SamanGholami- I think it requires an ad-hoc approach to solve the question. Not every square can be solved in this way as mentioned in Wikipedia!

Comment: Seriously, why the downvotes?

Comment: @Veritas I think, some people that doesn't know the answer then downvoting i think.

Comment: Brute force ? (starting from a void square, try all possible sizes - up to full square - and for a given size try all possible positions; repeat with the remaining space). This will be horribly slow and will explode the recursion stack :( Random attempts ? (do the same but picking the sizes randomly without repetitions; for placement find all possible places an pick one randomly). This will be terribly slow as well :( You can *slightly$ improve processing time by keeping a list of the largest empty square that can fit around every place.

Answer (score 0):

As Yves Daoust said the algorithm to solve this is going to be slow. The first challenge is to determine what squares COULD be combined to fit into your big square. Then figure out if they WILL fit in there.

I would first filter by area.

To answer the first part you need to look for a combination of squares that will fit into your big one. There are likely multiple combinations as a 5x5 square takes up the same area as a 3x3 with a 4x4 square. This is a O(2^n) problem in itself.

Then attempt to arrange them.

I would make a matrix that is the size of your big square. Then starting at the topmost then right most index add in a square by marking the matrix positions as occupied by that square. Then move to the next unoccupied space, based on the previous rules adding an unused square. If no square fits then remove the previous square and continue to the next. This is a method begging for recursion.

As I said at the beginning this is a SLOW way to do it but it will give you a solution if one exists.

Comment: After thinking about it a minute I realized the first part of the algorithm I suggested is "Subset-Sum" an problem that has been shown to be NP-Complete which suggest (but doesn't prove) that your problem is at least NP-Hard

Answer (score 0):

I used a dynamic programming approach for solving this. but it works until n ~ 50. I stored a solution as a bitset for efficiency:

You can compile the code yourself with:
**$ g++ -O3 -std=c++11 squares.cpp -o squares**

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

constexpr auto N = 116;

class FastSquareList {
 public:
  FastSquareList() = default;

  FastSquareList(int i) { mask_.set(i); }

  FastSquareList operator+(int i) const {
    FastSquareList result = *this;
    result.mask_.set(i);

    return result;
  }

  bool has(int i) const { return mask_.test(i); }

  void display() const {
    for (auto i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
      if (has(i)) {
        cout << i * i << " ";
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

 private:
  bitset<N + 1> mask_;
};

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  vector<list<FastSquareList> > v(n * n + 1);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    v[i * i].push_back(i);
    for (int a = i * i + 1; a <= n * n; ++a) {
      int p = a - i * i;
      for (const auto& l : v[p]) {
        if (l.has(i)) {
          continue;
        }

        v[a].emplace_back(l + i);
      }
    }
  }

  for (const auto& l : v[n * n]) {
    l.display();
  }

  cout << "solutions count = " << v[n*n].size() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

an example:

```
$ ./Squares
15
9 16 36 64 100 
25 36 64 100 
1 4 9 16 25 49 121 
4 36 64 121 
4 100 121 
4 16 25 36 144 
1 16 64 144 
81 144 
4 16 36 169 
4 9 16 196 
4 25 196 
225 
solutions count = 12
```